# disabled input inside ajax using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input").attr("disabled", true);
    </script>
</head>
    <style>
        #click{
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        width:200px;
        }

        #content{
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        width:200px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="click" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <a onclick="sendRequest('content.php','','content')">click</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="content">
            this is content
        </div>
    </body>
```

this is my content.php

```
<input type="text" />
```

this is my ajax.js
http://tny.cz/cb20dc87

i want input in the content.php disabled, can someone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Where did you get that ajax script from its awful

Answer (score 0):

Change your  content.php to

```
<input type="text" disabled />
```

Comment: i want disable it using jquery

Comment: Ahh why... anyway you'll have to disable it after you load it, probably somewhere in your ajax success callback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `sendRequest()` function, but here's how you do it with standard jQuery:

```
$('#content').load('content.php', function() {
    $("#content input").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

The callback function runs after the AJAX call completes. Presumably your `ajax.js` provides similar functionality.

Comment: In your `<script>` tag, in place of the code you already have there.

Comment: my content.php become

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document)ready(function(){
  $("#input")attr("disabled",true);
 });
</script>
<input type="text" id="input"/>

Comment: I didn't understand that you were trying to operate on the data loaded via AJAX. I've updated my answer, although you'll have to adapt it to the API you're using instead of jQuery.